# SD Card Bootable ASUS Eee PC not saving files, configuration or Installed program

Tags: linux, linux-mint, boot, sd-card

I used my Dell Inspiron laptop running Windows 10 Home and  rufus-3.8 (create bootable USB) software, created a bootable  Linux Mint SD card for Asus Eee PC 900 series. Now Aus Eee PC is booting fine with Mint Linux and I can access the WiFi and Install some software. The problem is it is not saving anything. Once the system is rebooted, it becomes like a fresh Installed Mint Linux losing all saved files, losing WIFI password and all installed software as well as configurations. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Live systems don't store anything unless you create them with persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Rufus as of version 3.7 supports persistence for Ubuntu and Debian (**experimental**).

Have a look at the changelog for 3.7 at [the Rufus site](https://rufus.ie/) - it contains a lot of *should, may, if* and special considerations ...

So at the moment I would not expect it to work reliably for mint.